# What factors do you choose to pick a PC Chassis or Case?

Tags: case, case-mods, chassis

When you're shopping around for a PC case or Chassis, what factors do you use for picking a computer case?  Are there any non-technical criteria you factor into your decision?

Answer (score 1):

### Determine what you want

- Where do you want to plug in your USB devices?
  Do you put it **under** the desk? USB port should be on top.
  Do you put it **on** the desk? USB port should be on the bottom.
- What kind of audio jack do you need on the front? HD Audio?
- What speed do you need? USB3 port on the front?
  If your desired case only has USB2, but you want USB3, is there an upgrade kit?
- Do you want nice cable management?
- Do you want your PSU on the top or on the bottom?
- Do you want a screw-less case?

### Determine what you can get

Big resellers these days have YouTube channels where they showcase computer cases. This is a great place to learn about features of cases that you might not even know about:

- [NewEgg Computer Cases YouTube playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFFAC3E6D4D751471&feature=plcp)

### Determine what works

- Does your mainboard come with any 3.5" front panel snap-ins?
  If so, do you even have a 3.5" slot on the front panel of your desired case?

Answer (score 1):

Factors I look at:
1. Case size (where will it go in my office)
2. Internal space, what expansion cards/drives are going into the case (what am I using it for)
3. Noise (what is the environment like, do I need a case that is designed for low noise)
4. Cooling (Am I going to run high-spec stuff that needs high airflow or water cooling)
5. Interfaces (Socket type and locations; high/low, front/back)
6. Cosmetics (Does it need to be seen, do I want some eye-candy)
7. Future proofing (Will I need more of any of the above in future)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

**Where am I going to put the damn thing?**

If it's going off in the corner somewhere then a full tower for maximum expandability is fine. If I want to create a [mobile station](http://www.everythingofficefurniture.com/computercarts.html) then I'll get something smaller, maybe one that will attach to the back of the monitor. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

- Making sure it has enough and good quality (e.g. usb 3.0)
  usb/microphone/headphone ports.
- Size
- Drive bays
- How **awesome** it looks